# need help on Custom Metadata Type

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-metadata

I  have one object Lead Support.In lead Support i have one Field `QueueLabel__C`.

And I created one Custom Metadata with Name Queue_metadata and in that i have one field `Queue_Label_c`

Requirement:when I am going to enter a record in `Lead_Support` Object it needs to check Quueulabel with same name is available in Metadata Object(`Queues_Label__mdt`) or not and if not then Error.

I am not able to make it bulkify.Please suggest

```
trigger CheckQueue on Lead_Routing__c (before insert,before update){
    list<String>Queulabel=new list<string>();
    for(Lead_Routing__c lc:trigger.new){
    Queulabel.add(lc.Queue_Name__c);
    }
    list<Queues_Label__mdt> listq=new list<Queues_Label__mdt>([select   Queue_Spec_Label__c FROM Queues_Label__mdt]);
    for(Lead_Routing__c lc:trigger.new){                  
          system.debug('lc>>>>'+lc);
        for(Queues_Label__mdt ss:listq){                  
               system.debug('ss>>>>'+ss);
           integer count=0; 
            System.debug('Inside next for count'+count);
            if(lc.Queue_Name__c!=ss.Queue_Spec_Label__c)   
            {
                 System.debug('Inside If list count'+count);
               count++;
                System.debug('count>>>'+count);
                if(count==1){
                     System.debug('Inseide If count'+count);

                    lc.adderror('Queue Label is Wrong');
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those rare cases where salesforce allows a query inside a loop, because queries to custom metadata types are free, so you should take advantage of that behavior.

```
for(Lead_Routing__c record: Trigger.new) {
    if([SELECT COUNT() 
        FROM Queues_Label__mdt
        WHERE Queue_Spec_Label__c = :record.Queue_Name__c] == 0) {
        record.Queue_Name__c.addError("Value does not exist.");
    }
}
```

If you need to do something else with the metadata, you may want to query it into a variable instead, but since such queries are basically free, it probably doesn't matter for most trivial cases.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can query in the loop without hitting the limit (as it custom metadata), you can and should avoid it.

First query the metadata label into set

```
Set<String> mdLabelsSet = new Set<String>();

for(Queues_Label_mdt mdRecord : [select Queue_Spec_Label__c FROM Queues_Label__mdt])
    mdLabelsSet.add(mdRecord.Queue_Spec_Label__c);
```

Loop over the trigger record and check it the value exists in the set

```
for(Lead_Routing__c leadRouting : trigger.new){
    if(! mdLabelsSet.contains(leadRoutng.Queue_Name__c)){
        leadRouting.adderror('Queue Label is Wrong');
    }
}
```